# An upper Bound for $(f(a))^2$, $a\in[0,1]$ in terms of $\int_0^1(f(x))^2dx$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

Is there any way to find an upper Bound for $(f(a))^2$, $a\in[0,1]$ in terms of $\int_0^1(f(x))^2dx$.

There is a commonly used upper bound  in terms of $\int_0^1(f_x(x))^2dx$, but I do want to make use of $f_x(x)$.

However, $f(x)$ is allowed to be smooth enough.

I do appreciate in advance helping me with this.

Comment: Without further assumptions on the regularity of $f$ it is not possible to bound the value of $f$ in a single point in terms of the $L^2$ norm of $f$, since the first one can be arbitrarily large without affecting the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Regularity like smoothness?

Comment: get $f\in C^1[0,1]$, now what's your answer?

Comment: The function $f$ might have an awful peak at $a$, but  the $L^2$-integral of $f$ is small nevertheless.

Comment: Still the same. Take $f(x)=\sqrt{n}\cdot x^n$ and you will have a function with a bounded $L^2$ norm and an arbitrarily large value in $x=1$.

Comment: Oh, alas, I guessed so; thanks.